# Rotacionar imagem android sem redimensionar ela?

Tags: android, imagem, resize

Estou "traduzindo" um programa escrito em c# para Android, e tive um problema durante realizar a rotação de uma imagem. O código funciona normalmente, mas retorna uma imagem de tamanho diferente da original, já entendi o motivo da nova imagem ter um tamanho diferente, mas como eu posso fazer essa imagem voltar no mesmo tamanho da original, deixando de fora as pontas da imagem?

A imagem rotacionada não é exibida para o usuário, é apenas usada internamente para realizar alguns cálculos.

```
public static Bitmap Rotate(Bitmap source, int anchorX, int anchorY, float angle)
{
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.postRotate(angle, anchorX, anchorY);
    return = Bitmap.createBitmap(source, 0, 0, source.getWidth(),
            source.getHeight(), matrix, true);
}
```

**Código original de C#**:

```
public static Bitmap Rotate(Bitmap image, Point offset, float angle)
{
    if (image == null) return null;
    Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
    rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution,  image.VerticalResolution);
    Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp); 
    g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
    g.RotateTransform(angle);
    g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);
    g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0)); 
    return rotatedBmp;
}
```

Comment: Qual é o código original em C#?

Comment: public static Bitmap Rotate(Bitmap image, Point offset, float angle)
        {
            if (image == null) return null;
            Bitmap rotatedBmp = new Bitmap(image.Width, image.Height);
            rotatedBmp.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(rotatedBmp);
            g.TranslateTransform(offset.X, offset.Y);
            g.RotateTransform(angle);
            g.TranslateTransform(-offset.X, -offset.Y);
            g.DrawImage(image, new PointF(0, 0));
            return rotatedBmp;
        }